# Extract variables from javascript string to create eval() scope

Tags: javascript, eval

I have an applications where admin can use JavaScript to write their own expressions if certain situations match or not.

At this moment I create an environment where the user could enter something like this:

```
global.myVariable.d > 10 && global.myOtherVariable.w < 5
```

I will call `eval("global.myVariable.d > 10 && global.myOtherVariable.w < 5")`

If I don't set up a global object that contains ALL the variables, the eval will throw an error (global.myVariable is undefined)

But setting all possible keys in the global object so it can match all the possible myVariables is a huge task, so I want to set only those keys that are needed in the specific eval string.

Is there a smart way to filter variables, from such a javascript string? 
Ofcourse everything after global. and until . can be regexed, but what about global["myVariable"]
or even more complex notations like `let mondial = global; mondial.myVariable`;

If I know 'myVariable' is asked, I can create the global {} before calling the eval string.

Comment: Best you can do is make `global` a proxy.

Comment: What do you want `global.myVariable.d` to return if `global.myVariable` is undefined?

Comment: Then the eval can evaluate to 'false' but that is what I mean: I need to examine the eval string, so I can prepare the global object so the string evaluates without error.

Comment: Do you want to get a default value for all the properties that are not set or simply get `false`? In the second case, you can simply enclose the `eval` function in a `try { eval ('...'); } catch (e) { }` block

Comment: I think bergi understood.
I want to know what the global object should look like before calling 'eval'

So my example should be read by this solution, and returning:

Comment: var global= { myVariable: { d: 12 }, myOtherVariable: { w: 3}}

Comment: if the eval string is "Number(global.whatIsThis) > 0" it should create:

Comment: var global = { whatIsThis: 2 }